# Update Spreadsheet with google API for continuous response using node js

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have registered a webhook which constantly generates the data. It has several fields, primary field is id. I am updating this data in a postgres table with update query. The problem is, I have a google sheet and the same data is there. After updating postgres table, I want to update the row in google sheet. How can I use googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.values.update() function to update the row with a specific id.
The code I wrote is like this:

```
                     let listOfLists = []
                     jsonArray.forEach(obj => {
                         const values = Object.values(obj);
                         listOfLists.push(values);
                       });
                    await googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.values.update({
                         auth,
                         spreadsheetId,
                         range: "'Sheet1'",
                         valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
                         resource: {
                             majorDimension: "ROWS" 
                             values: listOfLists,
                         },
                     });
```

Comment: I have 3 questions. 1. What is your current issue? 2. Can you provide the sample value of `listOfLists`? 3. Your `auth` can be used for putting the values to Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API?

Comment: To answer your questions, 1. The current issue is, I want to update a specific row for that specific ticket_id. 2. listOfLists has values from json response, which is basically a list of lists. Example would be, [[1022, 'ab', 'cd',  'de'], [1023, 'xyz', 'hbw', 'pyg']]. 3. Yes, I am using the same auth for inserting data in the google sheet, and that is working fine.

Comment: Assume that there's already a row in sheet with ticke_id = 1022. From the new response, I want to update the contents of the row. How can I pass the ticker_id parameter in 'range', so that only that row will affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to update rows of the Spreadsheet by searching `ticket_id`.
- The sample value of `listOfLists` is `[[1022, 'ab', 'cd', 'de'], [1023, 'xyz', 'hbw', 'pyg']]`.
- From this sample value, in your situation, the value of `ticket_id` is column "A".
- You want to achieve this using googleapis for Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for Google Spreadsheet with Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const googleSheetsInstance = // Please use your client.

const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set your Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // This is from your script.
const listOfLists = [[1022, "ab", "cd", "de"], [1023, "xyz", "hbw", "pyg"]]; // This sample value is from your comment.

const obj = listOfLists.reduce((o, r) => ((o[r[0]] = r), o), {});
const {data: { values }} = await googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.values.get({auth, spreadsheetId, range: sheetName});
await googleSheetsInstance.spreadsheets.values.update({
  auth,
  spreadsheetId,
  range: sheetName,
  resource: {values: values.map((r) => obj[r[0]] || r)}, // or values.map((r) => obj[r[0]] || Array(r.length).fill(null)),
  valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
});
```

- When this script is run, first, the values are retrieved from the sheet. And, the values of `ticket_id` of `listOfLists` are searched from column "A" of the retrieved values. And, the updated values are put on the sheet.
- In this sample, 2 API calls are used.

#### Note:

- If the values of `ticket_id` are not column "A", please modify `const obj = listOfLists.reduce((o, r) => ((o[r[0]] = r), o), {});` and `resource: {values: values.map((r) => obj[r[0]] || r)},` for your actual column.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)